How do i add select all / deselect all in infinite scroll of list view on flutterflow
How do i add select all / deselect all in infinite scroll of list view on flutterflow when data is coming inside a container from supabase. I dont see any option for selecting all for the items inside list item. Its being fetched from supabase to fluterflow
[Here's the image and layout im referring to] (https://i.sstatic.net/cPHshgYW.png)the list and page is set up like this
